# How can i get PHP variables on to a redirected page

Tags: php, post

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to create a simple contact form. The form works as expected and I have set it to generate a random number as a booking reference number.

So users fill out the booking request form which sends a post request to the mail file that processes the information and creates a booking reference. (all works perfectly).

Then the user is redirected to a mail-success page. On that page, I would like to display the booking reference number that is generated previously.

Any ideas on the best way to achieve this.

Comment: 2 options put the code in the url you send the user to, or use sessions

Comment: `header('Location: redirect_url?reference_number='.$reference_number.'');`

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? You will get a much better response here on SO if you read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Thank You tim,

I took your advice and used sessions to get it working.

Here is my working code

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<?php include 'header.php';?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="container">
<div class="alert-success text-center">
    <h1>Your Booking has been accepted</h1>
    <p>Your Booking Reference Number is: <?php echo $_SESSION['bookingRef']; ?> </p>
    <p>If you need to make changes, or cancel your booking. Please call us.</p>
    </div>

</div>

<?php
// remove all session variables
session_unset();

// destroy the session
session_destroy(); 

?>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```